# Compile Inno Setup script (.iss files) with Maven?

Tags: java, maven, windows-installer, inno-setup

I have a build workflow in which I transform a `.jar` to an executable binary (`.exe`) with the help of the launch4j maven plugin. I would like to create a `.msi` installer for this `.exe`, and I've used Inno Setup 5 to create a script to do this which works fine. But it would be even better if I could compile the script using a Maven plugin, so that I can create the installer package automatically in my build process. Is there a way to achieve this? I've looked at the `exec` Maven plugin, but I'm not sure how to configure it, or if it's even capable of executing `compil32`.

Comment: Which command would you run manually from the command line ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not want to use `Compil32.exe`, that's Inno Setup GUI.

Use `ISCC.exe` command-line compiler, like:

```
ISCC.exe setup.iss
```

So the [`exec:exec` goal](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/usage.html) configuration will be like:

```xml
<configuration>
  <executable>ISCC.exe</executable>
  <workingDirectory>...</workingDirectory>
  <arguments>
    <argument>setup.iss</argument>
  </arguments>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thank you Martin. When I run exec:exec I get `[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) on project xxx: The parameters 'executable' for goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec are missing or invalid`. I can't get it to work no matter which configuration I try. Any help?

Comment: I had to add an explicit phase to the execution, a la `<phase>install</phase>`, to get it to work. Thanks for your help.